# Search/count and aggregate for different terms

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently querying as follows:

```
"query": {
  "query_string": {
    "query": "direction:OUTGOING AND prot:https OR prot:http OR prot:smtp AND unixtime: [1410812748000 TO 1416899148000]",
    "fields": [ "direction", "unixtime"]
  }
```

What I need is a summation of all findings for the searched protocols (in this case http, https and smtp):

```
http: 5434,
https: 32,
smtp: 18
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using facets

```
curl "localhost:9200/myindex/_search?pretty=true&search_type=count" -d '{
 "query":
{
     "query_string" :
     {
          "query": "proto:http OR proto:https OR proto:smtp"
     }
 },
 "facets": {
     "hits": {
         "terms": {
             "field": "proto"
         }
     }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since facets are deprecated, using aggregations is the way to go.

```
curl "localhost:9200/myindex/_search?pretty=true&search_type=count" -d '{
   "query":
   {
       "query_string" :
       {
           "query": "proto:http OR proto:https OR proto:smtp"
       }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "hits": {
         "terms": {
         "field": "proto"
     }
   }
 }
}'
```